# Is there a way to have content blocks switch out for mobile vs desktop email viewing?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, content-builder

Is there an easy way to have content blocks switch out for mobile vs desktop email viewing? We would like to have one call-to-action if someone is looking at the email on their phone vs. on desktop.

Comment: Simply, I wouldn't do this even if it were. I would aim at [responsive email design](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/)

Answer (score 0):

I saw a demo of this, using standard Salesforce config at a *Lightning Roadmap* edition of the London Salesforce Developer meetup. This was back in April/May (2018) and was safe-harbour then, but not sure if/when it will actually drop.
The talk was videoed and can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCt6wfYvBPM).

Without this you could potentially use the useragent for this, or maybe even css media queries.